# Django: Lat / Long FloatFields not Saving

Tags: django, forms, django-models, save, django-formwizard

So I had a formwizard working perfectly, but then changed 2 things and now am receiving a `InternalError` database error. First, I specified templates using `get_template_names`.

forms.py:

```
TEMPLATES = {'0': 'formtools/wizard/wizard_form.html',
             '1': 'formtools/wizard/wizard_form.html',
             '2': 'formtools/wizard/wizard_map.html'}

class CreateWizard(SessionWizardView):
    get_template_names(self):
        return [TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]]
```

Secondly, I added `FloatFields` to the model being saved and in the form itself:

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    ....
    latitude = models.FloatField()
    longitude = models.FloatField()
    ....

class StepThreeForm(forms.Form):
    ....
    latitude = forms.FloatField()
    longitude = forms.FloatField()
    ....
```

I'm not sure why I am receiving `InternalError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block`. Here is the traceback:

```
File "/myapp/lib/python2.7/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/myapp/lib/python2.7/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  20.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/myapp/lib/python2.7/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  48.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/myapp/lib/python2.7/django/contrib/formtools/wizard/views.py" in dispatch
  223.         response = super(WizardView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/myapp/lib/python2.7/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  69.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/myapp/lib/python2.7/django/contrib/formtools/wizard/views.py" in post
  286.                 return self.render_done(form, **kwargs)
File "/myapp/lib/python2.7/django/contrib/formtools/wizard/views.py" in render_done
  328.         done_response = self.done(final_form_list, **kwargs)
File "/myapp/myproject/myapp/forms.py" in done
  82.       instance.save()
File "/myapp/myproject/myapp/models.py" in save
  112.         super(Thing, self).save()
File "/myapp/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  463.         self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
File "/myapp/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  551.                 result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)
File "/myapp/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/manager.py" in _insert
  203.         return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
File "/myapp/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/query.py" in insert_query
  1593.     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "/myapp/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  910.             cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: InternalError at /
Exception Value: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

Those are the only two things that I changed, along with adding a template at step 3 of my wizard. I cannot figure out why this would alter the functioning of my wizard. Can you help me figure out why I am now getting this error? Thanks for any ideas on this confusing problem!

---

EDIT: I updated my schema via south after adding these fields. Additionally, I tried using `DecimalField` rather than `FloatField` but still got a db error.

Comment: Did you add those fields to your database?

Comment: Thanks yes I migrated my schema via south.